# Как вывести иконку под "мостом" обеспечив визуальное перекрытие?

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandexmapkit

Нужно разместить иконку на уровне дороги, находящейся под другой дорогой, т.е. фактически под мостом. Принципиально, чтобы было видно - иконка перекрывается дорогой сверху и иконка частично скрыта.
Вопросы: можно ли размещать иконку в мобильном SDK в выбранном слое/уровне?
Можно ли отрисовывать линии и полигоны на выбранном слое/уровне так, чтобы объекты на слоях выше полностью  или частично перекрывали пользовательские объекты?

Answer (score 0):

Так сделать не получится.

Мосты у Яндекса (эстакады, тоннели и прочие многоуровневые развязки) не рисуются на разных слоях, чтобы можно было между ними расположить свои объекты или их подслои.

MapKit может лишь самостоятельно раскидывать получаемые сегменты дорог выше или ниже друг друга при отрисовке, вычитывая для этого из их данных нужный уровень. В [Народной карте](https://n.maps.yandex.ru/) немного можно понять реализацию. Уровень на развязке там - фактически лишь некий тег.